# On Plato's Transmigration of Souls

Tags: plato, ancient-philosophy, greeks, souls, immaterial-soul

In Plato's theory of *transmigration of souls,* do some souls ever make it to a place of eternal bliss or get remanded to a place of eternal punishment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plato does not develop a systematic and consistent theory of transmigration.

Instead in three of his works he inpolates some remarks of Socrates about the topic or Plato recounts a whole myth:

- Gorgias 523a-527e
- Phaedo 107d-115a
- Republic 613e-611b

Sokrates holds a rather detailed speech about the otherworldly court of justice in Gorgias 524ff. There are three types of judgement of the souls: The soul is either sent to the blissfull islands, or to the tartaros for improvement, or to the tartaros for eternal punishment.

The speech of Sokrates in Phaedo makes clear that those souls, which have to stay in the underworld but nor for further punishment in the tartaros, live at a certain lake (Acherousian lake).

The final myth in the Republic, book X 613ff, is different. The myth describes how the souls eventually come back from the underworld to the real world: The souls themselves choose from a large set of possibilites their favourite type of living for the next incarnation.